# как запустить BrowserMob Proxy

Tags: python, proxy, браузер

пытаюсь для начала просто запустить на линуксе browsermob proxy

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
server = Server(r"/home/admin/Downloads/browsermob-proxy/bin/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
```

выдает ошибку: browsermobproxy.exceptions.ProxyServerError: Can't connect to Browsermob-Proxy
в чем проблема?

Comment: наверное нужно добавить, операционная система Fedora 38, java установил 17.0.8, вообще задача состоит в другом но у меня просто в принципе не запускается никак  browsermob

Comment: так как всем плевать я сам разобрался, может кому поможет, у меня была версия java 17.0.8, я скачал 11 версию и в терминале поменял текущую версию командой "sudo alternatives --config java", и у меня заработало